# Why is the Class extend not getting private variable

Tags: php, class, private

The following code does not produce the output with the name `Jock`. I suspect because in the `class` `Animal` the `$name` is `private`, but the construct is `public` so should the subclass not be able to get the `$name` from the construct. I do not want to make `$name` `public`.

```
class Animal{
    private $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function Greet(){
        echo "Hello, I'm some sort of animal and my name is ", $this->name ;
    }
}

 class Dog extends Animal{
     private $type;

     public function __construct($name,$type) {
         $this->type = $type;
           parent::__construct($name);

     }
     public function Greet(){
         echo "Hello, I'm a ", $this->type, " and my name is ", $this->name;
     }
 }
   $dog2 = new Dog('Jock','dog');
   $dog2->Greet();
```

Comment: PHP/ Perhaps tag it as PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the private variable only accessed inside the same class, you need to use protected for the name variable in class Animal.

```
class Animal{
    protected  $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function Greet(){
     echo "Hello, I'm some sort of animal and my name is ", $this->name;
  }
}
class Dog extends Animal{
 private $type;

 public function __construct($name,$type) {
     $this->type = $type;
       parent::__construct($name);

 }
 public function Greet(){
     echo "Hello, I'm a ", $this->type, " and my name is ", $this->name;
  }
 }
$dog2 = new Dog('Jock','dog');
$dog2->Greet();
```

Answer (score 4):

You are right: delete the `private` variable or use `protected` in the first line of the class `animal` and you're fine.

```
class Animal{
    protected $name; //see here!
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function Greet(){
        echo "Hello, I'm some sort of animal and my name is ".$this->name ;
    }
}

$animal = new Animal("Gizmo");
$animal->greet(); //produces the desired result.
echo $animal->name; //this will throw an error - unable to access protected variable $name
```

`$name` won't be public since it is an argument used in the public constructor and is therefore confined to the scope of that function. The property `name` on the dog will be public however unless you use `protected`.

Dots are used to concat strings. However `echo` allows commas to output multiple expressions.

```
 public function Greet(){
     echo "Hello, I'm a ".$this->type." and my name is ".$this->name;
 }
```

Also when using double quotes; you can put the variables inside the string:

```
 public function Greet(){
     echo "Hello, I'm a $this->type and my name is $this->name";
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use setter & getter methods to help you modify and retrieve your instance variables without needing to declare them as public.

If you are using eclipse:
Right click on the class > Source > Generate Getters & Setters

which will create functions for all of your variables as so:

```
public String getName(){return this.name;}


public String setName(String name){this. name = name;  }
```

You could then use these methods to access and edit your class variables

Comment: The OP uses PHP, this answer doesn't refer to that.